# Getting IOError: [Errno Input overflowed] -9981 when setting PyAudio Stream input and output to True

Tags: python, portaudio, pyaudio

I'm trying to run the following code (an example from the PyAudio documentation) on my Mac (OS 10.7.2):

```
import pyaudio
import sys

chunk = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format = FORMAT,
                channels = CHANNELS,
                rate = RATE,
                input = True,
                output = True,
                frames_per_buffer = chunk)

print "* recording"
for i in range(0, 44100 / chunk * RECORD_SECONDS):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    stream.write(data, chunk)
print "* done"

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

The error that I'm giving is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyAudioExample.py", line 24, in <module>
data = stream.read(chunk)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 564, in read
return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames)
IOError: [Errno Input overflowed] -9981
```

I did a search for this error on Google and found that either making the chunk bigger or smaller could help. I tried this and it made no difference. I also tried adding in the following code to catch an overload exception:

```
try:
    data = stream.read(chunk)
except IOError as ex:
    if ex[1] != pyaudio.paInputOverflowed:
        raise
    data = '\x00' * chunk
```

That avoided the error, but instead of outputting my input audio, I heard a bunch of loud clicking.

To troubleshoot, I commented out the output=True line and the program ran fine, but did not output anything. I commented out the input=True and read in a Wave file instead and the stream was able to output the audio. I tried creating 2 streams, one for input and one for output, and that didn't work either.

Is there something else that I can do to avoid this error?

Comment: See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837097/pyaudio-recorder-script-ioerror-errno-input-overflowed-9981/34021599#34021599

Answer (score 1):

i run into the same situation when i manually install pyaudio (built portaudio from source),
a not so perfect workaround is to download the pyaudio for [Apple Mac OS X (Universal)](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/)
install it, which will only install it for python 2.6 and previous version. 
if you run your code with /usr/bin/python2.6, then you are done. 
but if you really want 2.7, copy the installed module (pyaudio.py, _portaudio.so) to the 2.7 folder /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/.

i donnot know why it does not work building the module from source.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in portaudio that until very recently caused many spurious overflow errors in OS X (see http://music.columbia.edu/pipermail/portaudio/2012-June/014167.html).

I have confirmed that the portaudio daily snapshot as of 2012-08-06 fixes the bug.

Comment: i have the latest portaudio (version 19.20111121_4) along with py27-pyaudio 0.2.7_0 and i still get this error no matter how i try to change the chunk size. i'm using mac os x 1.7.5 with python 2.7, can you share more info on how you got that portaudio daily snapshot to work, if you id?