# python pyaudio using multiprocessing

Tags: python, buffer, multiprocessing, pyaudio

I'm trying to grab samples from a stream of audio and put them in a shared Queue. I have another process that pulls from this queue.

When I run, I get this error:

```
* recording
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "record.py", line 43, in <module>
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 605, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames)
IOError: [Errno Input overflowed] -9981
```

EDIT: Apparently problem has been around for a while with no solution posted (I tried their suggestions):

- [PyAudio Input Overflowed -9981 - No solution working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081181/pyaudio-input-overflowed-9981-no-solution-working)
- [Geting IOError: [Errno Input overflowed] -9981 when setting PyAudio Stream input and output to True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567366/geting-ioerror-errno-input-overflowed-9981-when-setting-pyaudio-stream-input)
- https://github.com/jeysonmc/python-google-speech-scripts/issues/1

Here's (simplified) code:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import array
import time
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 2

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
left = Queue()
right = Queue()

def other(q1, q2):
    while True: 
        try:
                a = q1.get(False)
        except Exception:
            pass

        try:
                b = q2.get(False)
        except Exception:
            pass

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")
Process(target=other, args=(left, right)).start()

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    byte_string = ''.join(data)
    nums = array.array('h', byte_string)
    for elt in nums[1::2]:
        left.put(elt)
    for elt in nums[0::2]:
        right.put(elt)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
print "terminated"
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm on Mac OSX and Python 2.7, I installed `portaudio` through `homebrew` and tried both the `pip` and dmg installation of `pyaudio with no luck with either.

Comment: FYI your code works on my Fedora19 Python 2.7 with pyaudio 0.2.3. Problem likely specific to Mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The buffer overflow error is because your frames_per_buffer and read chunksize might be too small.
Try larger values for them i.e. 512,2048, 4096, 8192 etc

```
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 2

for CHUNK1 in [512,2048,4096,8192,16384]:
    for CHUNK2 in [512,2048,4096,8192,16384]:
        stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                        channels=CHANNELS,
                        rate=RATE,
                        input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK1)


        try:
            print CHUNK1,CHUNK2
            for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
                data = stream.read(CHUNK2)
        except:
            print "Boohoo"

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
```

---

**Update**

ok i think I got it. the pyaudio library will raise an overflow error if you wait too long before your next read.

```
byte_string = ''.join(data)
nums = array.array('h', byte_string)
for elt in nums[1::2]:
    left.put(elt)
for elt in nums[0::2]:
    right.put(elt)
```

this does a whole lot of very slow processing here. especially the two `for` loops which are in python. let the processing process get a whole chunk of mono-stream data which it can deal with instead of one int at a time.

```
import numpy as np
```

...

```
n=np.fromstring(data,np.uint16)
left.put(n[1::2])
right.put(n[0::2])
```

I don't even want to imagine what the `for` loops were doing to latency, but even the *relatively* minor performance improvement between using `array` and `np.array` are worth noting:

```
a=array.array('h',s)
n=np.array(a)

In [26]: %timeit n[1::2]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 669 ns per loop

In [27]: %timeit n[1::2].copy()
1000 loops, best of 3: 725 us per loop

In [28]: %timeit a[1::2]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.91 ms per loop
```

Comment: This code runs fine, but it's not the same problem I have. I'm adding data to multiprocessing queues - if I run valid values identified by your script (which was all of them), it doesn't fix the issue I see in the code I posted for the question.

Comment: awesome! that performance fix does it. I actually tried with the `array.array` version ditching the for loops, that worked as well. but numpy is the most performant, I'll use that. thanks!