# alternatives to pyaudio for audio processing in python?

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

what other options are there for recording audio and processing the raw signal integers in python besides pyaudio?

pyaudio is great, but I have found it [too unstable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804709/python-pyaudio-using-multiprocessing) for reliable use, especially on non-linux platforms. I don't really care too much about windows, but Mac OSX and other unix flavors I would like to support.

Comment: sounddevice seems to be a nice alternative these days: https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that snack can help you
http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkSnack

root = Tk()
tkSnack.initializeSnack(root)
c = tkSnack.Sound(file='test.wav')
c.record()
root.after(5000, c.stop)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can it record audio? doesn't seem that it can from the site

Comment: Using Snack you can create powerful multi-platform audio applications with just a few lines of code. Snack has commands for basic sound handling, such as playback, recording, file and socket I/O.

Comment: forgive me for my inability - I looked at the site and couldn't find the documentation or examples of recording audio anywhere. any idea where I could find that?

Comment: ugh would rather not depend on Tkinter...but thanks for the example.