# Pyaudio alternative in Python for speech to text translation

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am executing the code for speech to text translation in Python using the speech_recognition module; while executing the code the error is Pyaudio not installed.  When I am trying to install  the error is:
building '_portaudio' extension error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required.

is there any alternative for Pyaudio?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [alternatives to pyaudio for audio processing in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883036/alternatives-to-pyaudio-for-audio-processing-in-python)

Comment: Hello Amin, it will be great to get both ways either alternative or should I install Microsoft Visual?

Comment: Amin, thanks a lot for the link ill check if that is help full:)

Answer (score 2):

[python-sounddevice](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) is an alternative to PyAudio for recording and playing back audio streams, from microphone or to soundcard. It has a much more Pythonic API than PyAudio. And they also provide binary wheels for Windows and Mac OS, so no C++ compiler is needed.