# PyAudio recorder script IOError: [Errno Input overflowed] -9981

Tags: python-2.7, exception, io, audio-recording, pyaudio

The code below is what I use to record audio until the "Enter" key is pressed it returns an exception,

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import curses
from time import gmtime, strftime
import sys, select, os

# Name of sub-directory where WAVE files are placed
current_experiment_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
subdir_recording = '/recording/'

# print current_experiment_path + subdir_recording

# Variables for Pyaudio
chunk = 1024
format = pyaudio.paInt16
channels = 2
rate = 48000

# Set variable for the labelling of the recorded WAVE file.
timestamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S", gmtime())
#wave_output_filename = '%s.wav' % self.get('subject_nr')
wave_output_filename = '%s.wav' % timestamp

print current_experiment_path + subdir_recording + wave_output_filename

# pyaudio recording stuff
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format = format,
                channels = channels,
                rate = rate,
                input = True,
                frames_per_buffer = chunk)

print "* recording"

# Create an empty list for audio recording
frames = []

# Record audio until Enter is pressed
i = 0
while True:
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print "Recording Audio. Press Enter to stop recording and save file in " + wave_output_filename
    print i
    if sys.stdin in select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
        line = raw_input()
        # Record data audio data
        data = stream.read(chunk)
        # Add the data to a buffer (a list of chunks)
        frames.append(data)
        break
    i += 1

print("* done recording")

# Close the audio recording stream
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

# write data to WAVE file
wf = wave.open(current_experiment_path + subdir_recording + wave_output_filename, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(channels)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(format))
wf.setframerate(rate)
wf.writeframes(''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

The exception produced is this

```
Recording Audio. Press Enter to stop recording and save file in 2015-11-20-22:15:38.wav
925
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "audio-record-timestamp.py", line 51, in <module>
    data = stream.read(chunk)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 605, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames)
IOError: [Errno Input overflowed] -9981
```

What is producing the exception? I tried changing the chunk size (512,256,8192) it doesn't work. Changed the while loop condition and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem; there are 3 ways to solve it (that I could find)

1. set  rate=24000
2. add option    "exception_on_overflow=False" to  the "read()" call, that is, make it "stream.read(chunk, exception_on_overflow=False)"
3. use callbacks

Here is, for your convenience, an example o "using callbacks"

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, os, math, time,  pyaudio

try:
    import numpy
except:
    numpy = None

rate=48000
chan=2

sofar=0

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    global sofar
    sofar += len(in_data)
    if numpy:
        f = numpy.fromstring(in_data, dtype=numpy.int16)
        sys.stderr.write('length %6d sofar %6d std %4.1f  \r' % \
                         (len(in_data), sofar, numpy.std(f)))
    else:
        sys.stderr.write('length %6d sofar %6d  \r' % \
                         (len(in_data), sofar))
    data = None
    return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=chan, rate=rate,
                input=True, stream_callback=callback)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```